# Rhino Mocks, AssertWasCalled with Arg constraints

Tags: rhino-mocks

There's the interface IManager that I created a mock for. It has the method

```cs
void LogUserWithParams(string maskValue, E_LOG_LEVEL logLevel, 
string formatMsg, ref Array args);
```

I created a test to check that the method is called with any arguments.

```cs
Array logParams = Arg<Array>.Ref(Is.Anything(), new object[0]).Dummy;
manager.AssertWasCalled(man => man.LogUserWithParams(
    Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
    Arg<E_LOG_LEVEL>.Is.Anything,
    Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
    ref logParams
    )
);
```

It produced quite a weird message:
Argument 0 must be defined using: Arg.Is, Arg.Text or Arg.List

As you can see, all arguments are defined using Arg. Any idea about what's wrong with the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling it the way you did (with predefined variable) causes the exception to be thrown. This does the trick:

```
manager.AssertWasCalled(man => man.LogUserWithParams(
    Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
    Arg<E_LOG_LEVEL>.Is.Anything,
    Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
    ref Arg<Array>.Ref(Is.Anything(), new object[0]).Dummy
));
```

**Edit:**

I experimented on this simple program and everything seems to work as expected:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogUserWithParams(string maskValue, ref Array args);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loggerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ILogger>();
        loggerMock.Expect(l => l.LogUserWithParams(
            Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
            ref Arg<Array>.Ref(Is.Anything(), new object[0]).Dummy
        ));

        Array output = new Array();
        loggerMock.LogUserWithParams("[a-z]", ref output);
        loggerMock.VerifyAllExpectations();

        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy! Weird enough, your variant caused another mysterious error:

Argument 3 must be defined as: out Arg<T>.Out(returnvalue).Dummy

Therefore, I had to change the last argument to
ref Arg<Array>.Out(new object[0]).Dummy

It's fine as a workaround but does not give me any way to define further constraints on this parameter.

Comment: @IvanGerken: that's weird indeed. Can you try my sample whether it works for you? Also, what version of Rhino are you using (3.6 here)?

Comment: I tried your sample with the same version 3.6 of Rhino Mocks that I use in my project and it worked fine. I had to change only one line: "Array output = new Array();" to "Array output = new object[0];". I wonder how you managed to build your sample :)
Well, probably I stumbled upon some hardly-reproducible glitch of RM. In my test I mock almost a dozen of interfaces that come from a PIA. Thanks again for your help!